# Does Spring Boot application.yml support referencing to variables at key

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I need to have placeholders at map's keys inside Spring Boot `application.yml` that referencing to some existing variables (e.g. env variables / variables declared in props per profile)

```
SETTINGS_ID_1: 1001
SETTINGS_ID_2: 1005

settingsMapping:
    ${SETTINGS_ID_1}: hello
    ${SETTINGS_ID_2}: hi
```

So I expect that `settingsMapping` will have two keys: `1001` and `1005`, but real values are `SETTINGS_ID_1` and `SETTINGS_ID_2`.
Does Spring support such feature at `application.yml`? These placeholders work fine in map's values, but not in keys.

I tried the following options but without luck (props either have string values as is it, or exception `ParserException: while parsing a flow sequence`):

```
[${SETTINGS_ID_2}]
'[${SETTINGS_ID_2}]'
$SETTINGS_ID_1
'$SETTINGS_ID_1'
```

spring-boot version `2.2.2` (I guess it does not depend on the version, but anyway provided)

Comment: have you tried ? any error ?

Comment: sure I tried. in some cases it interprets as simple string, in other cases - yml parse exception. I updated post with details.